# Is there a cleaner way to write this if/else script?

Tags: swift

Learning Swift, curious if there is a cleaner way to write this code?

```
var apple = 1
var orange = 1
var kiwi = 1

if (orange > apple) && (orange > kiwi) {
    print("The orange is the best")
} else if (apple > orange) && (apple > kiwi) {
    print("The apple is the best")
} else if (kiwi > apple) && (kiwi > orange) {
    print("The kiwi is the best")
} else {
    print("None of them are the best")
}
```

Comment: Could you sort them and look at the first?

Comment: This question doesn't fit the format of this site well since this question is primarily opinion based. Stack Exchange actually has a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site that might be a better format for this.

Comment: Well you could eliminate the brackets around the comparisons for one, although why not use an array for this and just search for the max element with `maxElement`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a swift expert but from your code example, it seems like you could use the `max` function:

```
func max<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
```

And then you could even replace your `if {} else {}` structure with a `switch` statement.

Comment: This does not handle the = clause, what if apple and orange are both the best